# Access randomly a line in an array of map using feeders

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying to do a very simple operation but it gets really complecated when we are beginners in scala/gatling.

I just need to randomly pick a line in an array of map at every request...

I work on a JSON that looks like that:

```
[
 { "name": "a", "age": 33 },
 { "name": "b", "age": 34 },
 { "name": "c", "age": 38 }
]
```

So here is a draft what i am trying to do:

```
val user = feed(jsonFile("peoples.json"))
  .exec( session => {
    val someone = session[random()] // How to code that ?
    http(someone.age)
      .get("/users/${someone.name}")
  })

val scn = scenario("").exec(user)
```

The session seems to contain the user datas, but i don't know how to access it to build the path of my http request!

I have seen many different ways to do things that could be close to what i am trying to achieve but i couldn't find a clear working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Feeders Doc: http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.0/session/feeder.html?highlight=feeders

You can basically just use random feeder: `feed(jsonFile("peoples.json")).random`

Then you can access it with DSL:

```
val myFeeder = jsonFile("peoples.json").random
val userRequest = exec(http("someones ${age}")
      .get("/users/${name}"))

val scn = scenario("x").exec(feed(myFeeder),userRequest)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, in Scala, if you have a `Seq` accessing a random element would go like this

```
import scala.util.Random

val random = new Random
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
list(random.nextInt(list.length))
```

In `gatling` I believe it will give you `Seq[Map[String, Any]]` as an input. So you'd do something like

```
val random = new Random
val someone = session(random.nextInt(session.length))
http(someone("age")) ...
```

Comment: I think you meant `http(someone("age"))`